# cannot access website with port 2082

Tags: firewall

I am given a website in the form of `http://something.something.com:2082`. However, I can't access it, even though I can access`http://something.something.com`. I consulted the website owner and he said it is my firewall problem.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you in a corporate network or do you have control over your router/firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are connecting outbound, then it is not likely your firewall unless you are on a corporate network that filters both inbound and outbound traffic (most firewalls by default only filter inbound). If this is the case, you will need to speak with your IT group to see what can be done. Otherwise you may need to contact your ISP to see if they keep ranges of ports blocked (which would be odd for that particular port, but it does happen).